# Huge slowup using openCV matchTemplate on android

Tags: java, opencv

I'm making small project with tracking Mat pattern on Android camera frames by using openCV's `_matchTemplate_` method.

However, by the time my code reaches `_matchTemplate_` and `_minMaxLoc_`, framerate drops to ~1 per 10 seconds on my phone, yet in Android Profiler, memory and CPU usage are as flat as my grandma's ECG.

I assumed  it could be caused by script waiting to find matches, but I tried it on series of pictures on my PC and it took less than second to go through over 200 pictures (even without match it would simply point to top left corner, no hickups there).

Here is code for my tracking method:

```
public Mat simpleTrack(Mat input, boolean showCrosshair, boolean showTracker)
{
    if (firstRun)
    {
        crosshairDimensions(input);
        firstRun = false;
    }

    if (showCrosshair)
    {
        Imgproc.rectangle(input, new Point(rowstart, colstart), new Point(rowend, colend), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
    }
    else if (showTracker)
    {
        if (getTemplate)
        {
            template = input.submat(rowstart, rowend, colstart, colend);
            getTemplate = false;
        }
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(input, template, mRgbaM, Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
        Point top_left = Core.minMaxLoc(mRgbaM).maxLoc;
        Point bottom_right = new Point(top_left.x + framewidth, top_left.y + frameheight);
        Imgproc.rectangle(input, top_left, bottom_right, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    }
    //call Garbage Collector every n'th cycle iteration
    if (iteration % cycle == 0)
    {
        System.gc();
    }
    iteration++;
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if anyone had similar problem, the problem was caused by low-end Android device provided - on newer device the code started gaining speed.

What improved my performance even more was changing input Mat from RGB to Grayscale (or using threshold filter, so that script won't choke on a file that is over 10MB). I have also reduced resolution from 4k to HD.